# MySQL: One stored procedure for several tables

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I need to perform the same procedure for several tables in my DB. The poblem is that that procedure contains the following line:

```
DECLARE tableIt CURSOR FOR select id from table where column=inputParam ;
```

`table` is the table the procedure works with. And I can't find a way to make that table name to be dynamic, i.e. to read it from an input parameter.

Right now I have 8 different procedures (one for each table) which differentiate from each other only by one word (the name of the table).
That is really a pain since I have to make every change to the procedure 8 times.

Is it possible to parameterize the select statement for the CURSOR so I can have only one procedure??

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic cursors does not seem to be supported in Mysql. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cursors.html

You can work around it

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,133197,149099#msg-149099

"DROP VIEW IF EXISTS v1;

SET @stmt_text=CONCAT("CREATE VIEW v1 AS SELECT c_text FROM ", t_name);

PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt_text;

EXECUTE stmt;

BEGIN

DECLARE v_text VARCHAR(45);

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE c cursor FOR SELECT c_text FROM v1;"

Comment: Good idea. I think it's better to use a temporary table, though. A view is a global object so there is no thread-safety if you use that (two connections may try to create the same view for different tables).

Comment: The issue with temp table is its going to be an insert & can be slow. You can still have issue with concurrent access to this temp table. The query you have outlined also seems simple why not fire it from your java/perl/php code? You can then have dynamic queries built.